# How to check if a video file is fully watched using asp.net, c#

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, database

I have some youtube embeded in my site, I wanna keep track of the users who have fully watched a video?
how can I do that?

Comment: I know [Wistia](http://wistia.com/) has this feature.

Comment: asp.net runs on the server. The player runs on the client. You can only do this using JavaScript.

Comment: You can capture the events of pause, stop, move forward, end etc... to send signal to your server where the user is and if see its all.